# How was the Blade Runner replicant eye reflection effect done?

Tags: lighting, special-effects, eyes

I'm trying to recreate the Blade Runner eye reflection effect found in these examples:

[image: Blade Runner - Owl]

[image: Blade Runner - Android]

The closest I've seen is with a flash where the light bounces off in the eye and causes a bright red or white pupil but that would be inconvenient during a live shot like the movie. I've tried shining a bright light angled between the light, my eye, and the camera without much success.

Comment: Since this is primarily about a film effect, this might be better on http://avp.stackexchange.com/. But, it's also one of those things where the lighting setup could be done for stills as well.

Comment: You know, I've watched Blade Runner a lot of times, even studied it in school, but I've never actually associated that eye reflection in some scenes with being a replicant before.  I guess I've always assumed it was *just* a stylistic effect.  Now I have to watch the film again to see whose eye has a reflection and whose doesn't!

Comment: It will be interesting to see if the eye effect is continued in the Blade Runner sequel. I expect details will be published on the [Blade Runner 2](http://www.bladerunner-2.com) information website once available.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This effect was done by shining light directly in the same path as the lens. A half-translucent/half-reflective mirror (as in a "two-way" mirror) was placed in front of the lens at a 45 degree angle, and a beam of light directed on to that.

Like this:

```
         subject


           \    
darkness     \         <-- light
               \

            ^
         camera
```

The light would shine half through the mirror and half be reflected onto the subject; the camera's image would be half from the subject and half from whatever is to the left; to avoid that being an issue, one would presumably mask that with dark cloth to absorb the light shining through and avoid reflecting it back.

One could also use a ring flash to obtain a similar "on-axis" lighting effect, although of course the characteristic reflections would be ring-shaped, not the full circles seen in the replicants' eyes.

See [this article in the American Society of Cinematographer's magazine](http://www.theasc.com/magazine/mar99/blade/pg2.htm) for more on how these effects were done, including quotes from the film's cinematographer, Jordan Cronenweth. (He notes that "very subtle colored gels" were used as well.)

Comment: +1, but just a pane of glass would do it; that's how a TelePrompTer works.

Comment: @StanRogers: I remember reading the cinematographer saying he used half-translucent mirrors; found an article with the quote and linked it in the article. (I love this movie!)

Comment: Kind of want to try it with a pane of glass now. We'll see if my kids are cooperative this evening. :)

Comment: A "proper" beam splitter would probably be better when working wide (wide-angle lens and a wide-throw light) since you could work with a dimmer light and reduce flare, but with normal-to-long (and a restricted budget), you don't need to go there.

Comment: Half-translucent mirror would affect exposure by a whole stop; ideally you'd want something like 99% transmitted light, 1% transmitted light.  It's easier to make the light you're bouncing off it a lot brighter than it is to make the entire scene brighter.

Comment: Just  a note:  many animals (in particular those that need good night vision), have a special layer over the retina called the [Tapetum lucidum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tapetum_lucidum) which reflects the light. Humans don't have it, so you see their blood vessels (red eyes). Presence in dogs depends on breed and individuals.

Answer (score 3):

Essentially, mattdm's answer is correct. In addition, to the half-refelctive mirror, they used a tight, dimmable light to control when/how bright the eye reflections would appear.

Ridley himself discusses how they did it here:

https://youtu.be/IpzFOHEO8Sc

Comment: Can you summarize the info found in the video? As written, this is effectively a link-only answer. Please see the meta discussion, [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Comment: Hi Scottbb, I should have clarified, the other answer above is correct, and nearly complete. This video is additional verification that that is indeed how they did it, and provides just a bit more detail (it's also just fun to hear it from a primary source).